Max limit for ngrx store?
I using ngrx store for angular application, is there any limit on how much data can it store?
It was not a problem as of now. But I want to make sure that it doesn't ran out of size. I have 80MB of data fetching now which can increase in future.

ngrx store doesn't persist (by default) so the limit will be determined by hardware. By the sound of your requirements ("I have 80MB of data fetching now") are you sure you're not mistaking ngrx store for what something like IndexedDB is designed to do? ngrx is designed to hold component state not be used for storing large amounts of data.
